# How do you reset an extension's settings in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to do some custom settings for the C++ and CMakeTools extensions. But now I want to reset/revert everything to defaults. How do I do that?

- I tried uninstalling the extensions and re-installing, and they got re-installed with my custom settings wtf.
- I see no reset buttons in the UI
- I don't know where the per-extension settings are stored on my computer.

What am I not understanding? Why is this so unobvious?

Comment: go to your `setting.json` file(S) and remove the settings related to the extensions, if you uninstall extensions the settings are not removed

Comment: Maybe you have the settings sync extension turned on .. to sync your settings to the cloud ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a Settings tab (and apparently extension settings can be both in the User subtab and the Workspace subtab).

There's User, Workspace, and Default `settings.json`'s which you can open from `Ctrl+Shift+P`, start typing "settings.j", and see the 3 suggestions (the user settings file is located at `C:\Users\{USER_NAME}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json` (see [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) for all OS paths).

Compiler settings are in `c_cpp_properties.json`, Compiling settings are in `tasks.json`, Debugging settings in `launch.json`. These are in your project folder under the `.vscode` folder, and you can search them in `Ctrl+Shift+P` (but don't write .json at the end or it won't show up).

Also check your system environment variables for "CXX" and "CC" env variables which can also overwrite the compiler (and the ui says nothing about this).

---

Apparently there's [no way to reset all settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75430077/480859) (the "permanence" is a giant source of ux confusion, a meme decision in my professional opinion).

Luckily you can just go to Settings and write `@modified` to see all the settings you've changed!

[image: see modified settings]

Ok, so to finally answer: HOW do you RESET an individual setting?

This cannot be "googled": There's an invisible hover hitbox on the left side leading to a hidden settings gear (red dotted line):

[image: highlighted in red]

This ux is the source of the problem.

---

In VSCode, "removing"/"deleting" a setting means "resetting" it. Your settings are just "overwritings". So all auto-defaults should pop back into the UI after a VSCode restart, I hope. (also the aforementioned .vscode settings / env vars / build folder might still override)

Comment: You don't even need to restart it for settings to take effect. For example, if I toggle `jupyter.enableCellCodeLens`, the code lenses appear/disappear right away. But I don't know if it might be different on Windows, or for certain settings, or for other parts of the config for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [this feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76954), you cannot do this directly. However, you can open your `settings.json` file and find the extension settings, then manually remove them.

Keep in mind, removing the extension won't remove its settings. So reinstalling the extension will not reset it at all, but keep your previous configuration.

Comment: Alternately, you could just comment them out. VSCode's config files support comments. (They say they're JSON but really they're JSONC.)

Comment: It's worth adding that if you have any workspace-specific extension settings, you'd need to remove them from the workspace's `settings.json`.